# Is the google +1 button domain dependent or url dependent?

Tags: google-plus-one

Is the google +1 button domain dependent or url dependent?

Ie:

If exampledomain.com  has a +1 count of 20, will exampledomain.com/anotherpage  also have a count of 20 ?

Comment: Follow-up question: would a +1 of exampledomain.com/anotherpage add to the count of the +1s on the homepage exampledomain.com --- but a +1 of exampledomain.com would not add to the count at exampledomain.com/anotherpage    ?

Answer (score 1):

It is URL dependent. So if the homepage (exampledomain.com) has 20 +1's it does not mean any inner pages (exampledomain.com/anotherpage) are also considered to have 20 +1's as well.