# Impact of +1 on blogpost for the rootsite

Tags: seo, google, blog, google-plus-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the google +1 button domain dependent or url dependent?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18965/is-the-google-1-button-domain-dependent-or-url-dependent)

Lets say I have a blog at www.example.com . I have some blog posts and they are +1'd. 
What is the impact of these +1s for my Googlerank of www.example.com?

Couldnt find any SEO related topics about this. Maybe someone tested it or knows something related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Universal ranks relating specific pages to specific keywords are disappearing slowly in Google. **In the future** contextual search will be more relevant than ever. So your page positioning depends on the person that searches it, his/her search history, clicks, interests and friends on Google+ and what the user's friends have +1'ed.

Contextual search relevance will depend on how many people search while logged in Google.

**Now** you can find what you are looking for in [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/). Traffic > Plus one reports > Search impact